# Query for key value pair structure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a table structure as below :

```
Id (Identity): int  
GroupId:       int  
Field Id:      int  
Field Name:    nvarchar(1000)  
Value:         nvarchar(max)
```

This table can be viewed as a key-value pair structure.

So if I have the following records in the UI :

```
Due Date    | Target Date       | Status  
-----------------------------------
5-Jun-2013  |       4-June-2013 | Pending  
10-Jun-2013 |       8-June-2013 | Completed  
15-Jun-2013 |      11-June-2013 | Pending
```

In the database each column goes as a separate record. So the database will have:

```
Id  | Group Id  | Field Id  | Field Name    | Value  
-----------------------------------------------------------
1   | 1         | 1         | Due Date      | 5-Jun-2013  
2   | 1         | 2         | Target Date   | 4-Jun-2013  
3   | 1         | 3         | Status        | Pending  

4   | 2         | 1         | Due Date      | 10-Jun-2013  
5   | 2         | 2         | Target Date   | 8-Jun-2013  
6   | 2         | 3         | Status        | Completed  

7   | 3         | 1         | Due Date      | 15-Jun-2013  
8   | 3         | 2         | Target Date   | 11-Jun-2013  
9   | 3         | 3         | Status        | Pending
```

While retrieving back from database I would like to get output in the same format as I see in UI. What is the best way to get this result, considering the table will have a huge amount of data?

Any help in this regards will be really useful.

Comment: How can you tell from the data that 'Completed' and '10-Jun-2013' belong together?  It looks like there is no relation between the key-value pairs that make up a single row.

Comment: @user2485266 : What is the logic to group the records together. i.e. how did you separate  FieldId (1,2,3) for Id(1,2,3) from FieldId (1,2,3) for Id(4,5,6).

Comment: Change to a sane table design? Outside of a few situations, EAV is a poor choice.

Comment: Google [SQL Antipattern EAV](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sql+antipatterns+EAV), there are about a million articles explaining why EAV is a mostly a poor choice.

Comment: These are grouped by one field. Missed the field. Yes, I very well know this is a bad design but have inherited the problem. Also, this is just as extract of actual table. The actual table has other fields indicating value data type and others

Answer (score 1):

Whether this is a good design or not, you can accomplish what you want with the data as presented in the OP.  The key is to note that the difference between the ids identifies the rows.  I must emphasize that an explicit "record" reference should be included in the design, so I would call this message a hack.

```
select (id - FieldId),
       max(case when FieldName = 'DueDate' then value end) as DueDate,
       max(case when FieldName = 'TargetDate' then value end) as TargetDate,
       max(case when FieldName = 'Status' then value end) as Status
from t
group by (id - FieldId)
```

By the way, the fact that you have to store dates as strings is further indication of a problem with the data structure.  Even in an EAV structure, you can have "ValueStr", "ValueDate", "ValueInt" as separate columns to store different values (or use a sqlvariant type).

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
SELECT 
      MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'Due Date' THEN fvalue ELSE NULL END) [Due Date],
      MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'Target Date' THEN fvalue ELSE NULL END) [Target Date],
      MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'Status' THEN fvalue ELSE NULL END) [Status] 
FROM #tmp GROUP BY (id - FieldId)
```